# repeat command for every set of files

Tags: python

I'm working with DNA sequence data in a program called ObiTools. I would like to find a way to repeat a command for every set of files within the same folder.

For example, if I have the files

```
Sequence_A1_R1.fastq,
Sequence_A1_R2.fastq,
Sequence_A2_R1.fastq,
Sequence_A2_R2.fastq,
etc.
```

I would like to run the following command for every value of X, such that X is always the same value (no combination of different values).

> illuminapairedend Sequence_X_R1.fastq Sequence_X_R2.fastq > Sequence_X_pairedend.fastq

Is there a python script that could easily do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of quotation blocks. Also, provide a concrete example of what commands would be run for your set of concrete example files.

Comment: Is this a command line thing? You might try tagging your question with [shell] or [bash] or [batch] if it's windows. "Running a command" on files like that would be much easier at that level.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files are in **file_list** and already captive in earlier Python code, you could do something like this:

for file_pos in range(0, len(file_list), 2):
    command = "illuminapairedend " + 
              file_list[file_pos] +
              file_list[file_pos + 1] +
              "> Sequence_X_pairedend.fastq"
    os.system(command)

This last command is covered thoroughly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

---

**This is best only if you acquire the file list in Python.**  If the file list comes from elsewhere, it's almost certainly better to write the script in your command shell: **bash**, for example.